# firestoreの読み書きを自分のアプリ以外から禁止したい

Tags: firebase

私は今、firebaseを用いて、オープンソースでアプリケーションを作っています。

そのプロジェクトでは、firebase authenticationで認証されたユーザがクライアントJavaScriptからfirestoreを書き換えています。

firebaseの構成情報は、webに公開しても構わないもののはず(JSコードにハードコードして良いことになっているので)ですが、もし悪意ある者が私の構成情報をコピーして、自作のアプリケーションから私のアプリケーションのユーザとしてfirebase authenticationを実行した場合、その悪意あるアプリ〜ションもfirestoreのルールを回避して書き込めてしまうのではないですか?

firebaseのOAuth2.0では既定でlocalhostが許可されていますが、それを削除しないといけない、ということでしょうか。
firebaseのセキュリティの仕組みがわかりません。

なぜfirebaseでは構成類を公開しても問題ないのでしょう?
どうすれば悪意あるアクセスを回避し、私のアプリケーションでのみデータベースにアクセスできるようにできますか?